# If-control Java in script javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, if-statement

I have this javascript function:

```
function AnnullaModificaAbbonamento(){
    $("#imgModAbb").attr("src","imm/edit.png");
    $("#imgModAbb").attr("title","modifica");
    $("#imgModAbb").attr("onclick","ModificaAbbonamento()");    
    $("#submitModificaAbbonamento").remove();
    $("#primacol").text("");
    $("#secondacol").text("");
    $("#terzacol").text("");
    var primacol= "Tipo:&nbsp;<font id='h3'>a <%=a.getTipo()%></font><br>"
    +"Pagato: &nbsp;<font id='h3'> <%if (a.isPagato())
            out.println("<img src='imm/si.png'>");
        else
            out.println("<img src='imm/no.png'>");%></font><br> ";

$("#primacol").append(primacol);
var secondacol= "Data di Inizio:&nbsp;<font id='h3'><%=a.getDataInizio()%></font><br>"
+"Data di Scadenza:&nbsp;<font id='h3'><%=a.getDataScadenza()%></font><br>";
$("#secondacol").append(secondacol);
var terzacol="";
<%if (a.getTipo().equals("tempo")) %>

    terzacol="Punti bonus residui: <font id='h3><%=a.getPuntiBonus()%></font><br>"
    +"Lezioni fatte: &nbsp;<font id='h3'> <%=a.getLezioniFatte()%></font><br> ";

<%else%>
terzacol="Punti residui: &nbsp;<font id='h3'><%=a.getPunti()%></font><br>"
+"Lezioni fatte: &nbsp;<font id='h3'><%=a.getLezioniFatte()%></font><br>";

$("#terzacol").append(terzacol);

}
```

I'm trying to do the if-control inside a javascript function...first of all it is right? there is another method to do this?
Another thing: eclipse gives me an error in the else line. It says:

```
 Syntax error on token "else", delete this token
```

why?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see an ending %> for your second if/else.

Comment: Is the syntax error in Java or in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can insert an if in JSP. But two lines (at least) are inserted here so that makes your syntax invalid.

Use this :

```
<% if (a.getTipo().equals("tempo")) { %>
 ...
<% } else { %>
 ...
<% } %>
```

Comment: The generated java is longer than you think. Always use the braces in JSP.